# SQL Server restore problem

Tags: sql-server

Backup a simple model database

When restore to another server's database, path is correct and tick overwrite existing database and change to simple model in options

Error occurs

> The media set has 2 media families but
>   only 1 are provided

Comment: [Have you read this already?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/abf50e00-c9b0-4809-9e61-43ed8a53e968)

Answer (score 1):

What version of SQL you are using?
Are you trying to restore system database -MODEL or an user database?
Are you restoring using GUI or TSQL?

You might try running RESTORE FILELISTONLY to see the contents of the backup file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the backup consist of two files, but you restore only one of them.

Comment: thanks, solved, the list have more than two files, will split into two files, i misunderstand highlight one file is to restore one file

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the backup you took was a Full backup rather than a differential.